# How to make a command with 2 words in it Discordjs

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed

I am trying to code a discord.js bot for my community server and I was having some issues with making my help command. I have a command for `>help` that shows and embed with all the different categories of commands. It also shows how to view those other commands, but for me to be able to do this I need to be able to have commands like `>help fun` or `>help staff`. I tried to make the `>help fun` command but when I type it, it only takes the first argument and just shows me the `>help` embed. If someone could show me the code for a `>help fun` command that will just send a new Discord.MessageEmbed that would be great. This is the code I tried using:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'help fun',
description: "get some `fun` help!",
execute(message, args, Discord){
  
  const helpfunEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  
  .setColor('#9947d6')
  .setAuthor('Vero Commands List', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/746321327727706226/819556499088605214/Hypers.png')
  .setDescription("The Vero Bot prefix for `Ak's Basement` is `>`")
    .setThumbnail('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/hn8Iyc--j2npBvCjnAsXUt78zMovfsTj_DyRaBb1YdU/https/media.giphy.com/media/eEx0qRFYM1dyGQPAID/giphy.gif')
  .addFields(
    { name: '`>ping`', value: 'shows bot latency'},
  { name: '**Work In Progress**', value: 'More commands coming soon!'},
    )

message.channel.send(helpfunEmbed);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make the help command, and let the user pass "fun" as an argument, then base the bot's reply off that, that way you can have one command for all the help sections.

Comment: I tried to do this, and it works with the args, but if I write **>help fun** it sends both the **>help fun** and **>help** embeds. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

here's a code example,

btw [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/) has a whole explanation on this, so you might want to read it

Here a link if you want to that exact page;

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html

and here is a code sample,

I am assuming  `execute(message, >>>> args <<<<< , Discord)` (args) passes a array ( this code is according to the guide i said above)

```
module.exports = {
name: 'help'
description: "get some `fun` help!",
execute(message, args){

if(!args[0]) { // if no args were give : ex: ">help"

  const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#9947d6')
  .setAuthor('something here')
  .setDescription("A description")

 
// do whatever you want with the code and send it,
// assume prefix is >
// this is if there were no args: ">help" will be the command


return message.channel.send(helpEmbed);


} else if(args[0].toLowerCase() == 'fun') { // lowercase it so it will not be case sensitive ex: this would allow ">help FUn" and ">help fun"

const helpFunEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#9947d6')
  .setAuthor('something here')
  .setDescription("")

return message.channel.send(helpFunEmbed)
} else if(args[0] == 'info'){ // without ".toLowerCase()" will only allow : ">help info" and will give the below error we set if we use something like ">help Fun" 


// do something here (send your embed with help menu for info)


} else { // optional, if some one do a invalid category, it will send a error : ex: ">help dfsg"

return message.channel.send('Invalid category')
}
```

**with this you will not have to create individual command for each catergory***
we can just check the args to see if they provided any args or not (detailed explanation below)

ps: you would have noticed I have removed `Discord` from `execute(message, args)`
this is as you don't need to export Discord like this as you can just do
`const Discord = require('discord.js')` at the top. there will be no difference changing this, but I like to just require it at the top, if you want just add discord in there like `execute(message, args, Discord)`

**Simple explanation on what we do here**

first, we check if `args[0]` is undefined (if a user do ">help" without something in front of it, this would detect it and send

> then it will send the embed with the categories if this returns undefined

if a arg is given it will go to the `if-else` chain

checking if the args = to the category we set.

> if it is send the embed with the relevant command info to the user
> if its not equal to the category it checked it will go through all the if else chains looking if it matches
> if It does not match it will send the error " Invalid category" meaning the user sent a category that we were not looking for

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful and will make doing this help command alot easier!

Comment: np, if you found this helpful, mark this as the answer